# Permalink Redirection and Regular Expressions in WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, permalinks

I've got a pretty basic RegEx question but it's pressing enough that I don't have time to run down a tutorial on RegEx in order to answer it myself.

In short, I need:
/2009/01/28/post-name/

redirected to
/post-name/

As well as
/post-name/author-name/

redirected to
/post-name/

I promise to go take a class in RegEx before the month is out. Deal?

PS. Yes, I know that the Wordpress Redirection plugin will automate .htaccess but it won't write RegEx for me.

---

Solved using the Redirection plugin.

Source URL: /(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)
Target URL: /$4

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this, the answer (in WordPress permalinks anyway) is to use the aforementioned Redirection plugin. The source URL is: /(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*) and the target url is: /$4

Comment: Explaining that to non-savvy people, you're looking at a basic URL structure of /digit/digit/digit/string then grabbing the fourth value (/$4) and appending it back on to the original domain. Thank god for RegEx cheat sheets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As this may be found by someone in the future, I'm going to answer in as much detail as possible. I actually [posted a blog on the subject here](http://imperativeideas.com/changed-permalink-structure-now-404s/) where I could discuss it.

The simplest solution uses very basic regex in concert with the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin for WordPress. In this instance, you can use simple structures:

- (\d*) for a numeric string
- ([A-Za-z0-9-]*) for an alphanumeric string
- $# (in my case $4) to determine which of the outputs to keep
- a / for the directory seperator

So in the case of /yyyy/mm/dd/post-name we use:

- Source URL: /(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)
- Target URL: /$4

in order to output /post-name as a 301.

Don't forget to check the regex box!

[image: gui interface for the redirect]

Comment: I'm playing with this plugin and I could not enter a valid regex in Target URL. For the Source I have /(.*)+.html and I want to redirect all to /blog/$1.html .I've checked regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me directly through htaccess.

For Day and Name (/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/)

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /$4`

For Month and Name (/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/)

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /$3`

For Numeric (/archives/%post_id%)

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/archives/(\d+)$ /?p=$1`

**Note: Use it after https redirect**