# How do I remove/hide specific parts of my Wordpress url?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, get, permalinks

My current URL is below. I'm using a custom php function to pass three GET variables to the page "world":

```
http://wordpress.dev/hello/world/?one=Volvo&two=Ford&three=Chevy
```

How can I make my URL look like this?

```
http://wordpress.dev/hello/world/VolvoFordChevy
```

Some googling points me towards the .htaccess file but none of the tips are specific to my goal and I haven't worked much with htaccess.

Comment: You should read up more on RESTful practices.  URLs are for _resources_ (Uniform Resource Locator), so the way that you want your URL to look is actually asking the server for a _resource_ named `VolvoFordChevy`.  The `?` at the end of the URL indicates that the request for the _resource_ has ended and that the list of parameters that that _resource_ should meet has begun.

Comment: In short, regex would be able to do that for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774545/permalink-redirection-and-regular-expressions-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Generally URL rewriting being done by adding url rewriting rules in .htaccess file. Wordpress have a builtin functionality name Permalink to do it.

In Wordpress admin go to Settings → Permalinks panel (Options → Permalinks before WordPress 2.5), you can choose one of the "common" structures or enter your own in the "Custom structure" field using the structure tags for defining your choose of URL.
You can also find plenty of plugins for url rewriting in wordpress like:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-permalinks/
```

Comment: How does this answer the question, exactly?

Comment: The question is related to URL rewriting in specifically Wordpress. Andv wordpress provide URL rewriting through admin panel ( creating/updating .htacess file)